# Swift SpriteKit Game Center

Tags: swift, ios8

I have been trying to split my Game Center code into a helper class as per numerous tutorials on this website and others.

This is what I currently have in my GameViewController.swift

```
func loadGameCenter() {

    var localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()

    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {(viewController, error) -> Void in

        if (viewController != nil) {

        self.presentViewController(viewController, 
        animated: true, completion: nil) //POINT 1
        }
        else {
            println((GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated))
        }
    }
}
```

In my MenuScene.swift, which is a SKScene, I have this code.

```
func saveHighScore(highScore:Int) {

    if GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated {
        var scoreReporter = GKScore(leaderboardIdentifier: leaderboardID)
        scoreReporter.value = Int64(highScore)

        var scoreArray: [GKScore] = [scoreReporter]
        GKScore.reportScores(scoreArray, withCompletionHandler: {(error : NSError!) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                println("Error")
            }
        })
    }
}
func showGameCenter() {

    var vc = self.view!.window!.rootViewController! //POINT 2
    var gc = GKGameCenterViewController()
    gc.gameCenterDelegate = self
    gc.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerState.Leaderboards
    vc.presentViewController(gc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(gameCenterViewController: GKGameCenterViewController!) {

    gameCenterViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Now I have been trying to put the above mentioned code into a helper class called GameCenter.swift, which is a subclass of NSObject. I wrote this just after the class name to make the methods mentioned above accessible in my other Scenes (as per tutorials).

```
class var sharedInstance: GameCenter {
    struct Static {
        static let instance = GameCenter()
    }
    return Static.instance
}

class func loadGameCenter() {
    GameCenter.sharedInstance.loadGameCenter()
}

class func saveHighScore() {
    GameCenter.sharedInstance.saveHighScore(highScore)
}

class func showLeaderboard() {
    GameCenter.sharedInstance.showLeaderboard()
}
```

The problem I am having is that when I am trying to call certain class functions from my MenuScene.swift, for example "GameCenter.loadGameCenter()" or "GameCenter.showLeaderboard() ", it causes me issues at POINT 1-2.

In other words how would I need to rewrite my old existing code to make it work in a NSObject class. I am stuck and have being trying to figure this out for ages.
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also solved ages ago but just incase someone sees this. 
I simply put these functions in gameViewController for showing the Login screen or Menu instead of what I had previously in the Helper class.

```
func showGameCenterLogin() {

    self.presentViewController(GameCenter.sharedInstance.presentingViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func showGameCenterMenu() {

    GameCenter.showGameCenterMenu(self, viewState: .Default)
```

}

and than calling them with NSNotificationCenter when required.

To record the score I just call the function with the corrent score and/or leaderboard ID to save it, which is obvious and I can't remember why that caused me issues back than.

```
   GameCenter.sharedInstance.saveHighScore(highScore)
```